# How to read this xml data in php

Tags: php, xml

Trying to echo out the values in each column from a xml file
First column represents the key/name and the second represents the value

```
<report lang="en" name="Statssa Test" tz="134224928">
<stats/>
<tables>
<table cols="2" flags="16777216" id="unit_profile_fields" name="Profile" rows="6">
<header>
<col name="Name"/>
<col name="Value"/>
</header>
<row>
<col txt="Brand" val="0" vt="0"/>
<col txt="VW" val="0" vt="0"/>
</row>
<row>
<col txt="Color" val="0" vt="0"/>
<col txt="WHITE" val="0" vt="0"/>
</row>
<row>
<col txt="Model" val="0" vt="0"/>
<col txt="POLO TSI" val="0" vt="0"/>
</row>
<row>
<col txt="Vehicle type" val="0" vt="0"/>
<col txt="CHZD15244" val="0" vt="0"/>
</row>
<row>
<col txt="VIN" val="0" vt="0"/>
<col txt="AAVZZZAWZKU087256" val="0" vt="0"/>
</row>
<row>
<col txt="Year" val="0" vt="0"/>
<col txt="2019" val="0" vt="0"/>
</row>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not XML format at all, hello

Comment: @AksenP care to sure why not?

Comment: @AksenP but thats the format of the xml file they gave me, How can I read the values from this file

Comment: @Ricciillmatic, [loadXML](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: Where's the code to echo anything?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thats what Im trying to find out. But the xml format looks way different from what I find on the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//Load xml file
$xml=simplexml_load_file("note.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");

//loop table data into array
$items = array();
foreach($xml->tables->table as $key =>$value)
{
    $items[] = $value['rows']; 
}

//display first table data
for($i = 0; $i < $items[0]; $i++)
{
    //display each column item values/text
    foreach($xml->tables->table->row[$i]->col as $key =>$value)
    {
        echo $value['txt'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```